# REST API coverage tools (Python / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, rest, unit-testing, jsonschema

I am interested in generating a REST API coverage report. We're currently defining our API in RAML, and validating our unit test fixtures from both client and server via JSONSchema. We're also tracking unit test coverage already.

Is there any way (preferably in Python and/or Javascript) that I can track a set of (existing) unit tests and ensure that all related API resources/methods have been exercised, all status codes have been generated etc.?  At the moment the coverage reports will only tell us if we've exercised the code which implements the API, but not which parts of the API have been exercised during testing.

Comment: Can you just use regular unittests and make http requests to validate the REST api?

Comment: Yes, that's what we're currently doing, this question is about measuring coverage of the API itself to make sure we've touched all available resources / responses etc during unit testing.

Comment: We use unittests, plus Apache ab tool that exercise each HTTP method and API endpoint integrated in a shell script which runs as daemon thus guarantee real requests are made successfully and additionally do performance testing.

Comment: @spicyramen does that tell you (programmatically) which resources methods, endpoints, responses etc of your API have or haven't been tested?

Comment: Yes, but you need to do program it for each HTTP method and endpoint. Responses need to be handled as well. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apachebench-to-do-load-testing-on-an-arch-linux-vps